# how to use FileWriter

Tags: java

I wanted save the  text with JTextField, i did it , is working good, I have 3 JTextFile

1. ID
2. Name
3. Password

well now I want to load my Name and password by
 putting the ID into field of ID HERE, is all the code, that i have done just kindly   guys tell me how to load it again, thank you so much in advance.

```
    String id = jTextField1.getText();
    String name = jTextField2.getText();
    String last = jTextField3.getText();
    if (jTextField1.getText().isEmpty() || jTextField2.getText().isEmpty()           || jTextField3.getText().isEmpty()) {

    } else {
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("user.txt", true);
            writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            writer.write(id);
            writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            writer.write(name);
            writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            writer.write(last);
            writer.close();
            jTextField1.setText("");
            jTextField2.setText("");
            jTextField3.setText("");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use a `Scanner` maybe

Comment: well I have jTextField I want to use textfield bro

Comment: @SaboorHamedi a FileWriter is used to write to a File. You want to read from a file. So a FileWriter won't help. And the fact that you have a textfield is completely irrelevant to the way you read from files. Google for Java IO Tutorial, and try something. Using a Scanner is a good recommendation. Instead of discarding it, read the javadoc of Scanner.

Comment: Thank you bro for nice guiding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments from @RC and @JB Nizet's are correct.

To help you out, here is a simplistic program that provides methods for saving and loading values to and from your `JTextField`s. This should give you a starting point towards a more realistic program. I used Java's [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JTextFieldFun {
    private static String sep = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public void save(String filename, JTextField jTextField1, JTextField jTextField2, JTextField jTextField3) {
        String id = jTextField1.getText();
        String name = jTextField2.getText();
        String last = jTextField3.getText();
        if (id.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || last.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Empty text fields");
        } else {
            try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename, true)) {
                writer.write(sep + id + sep + name + sep + last);
                jTextField1.setText("");
                jTextField2.setText("");
                jTextField3.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void load(String filename, JTextField jTextField1, JTextField jTextField2, JTextField jTextField3) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            jTextField1.setText(reader.readLine());
            jTextField2.setText(reader.readLine());
            jTextField3.setText(reader.readLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding me really appreciate you, well this is working, but when I click on load button it gives me the last data, I want  put my id and click on load button, should give me  that specific id bro

Comment: I do not understand this new requirement. Since you agree that I answered the question, please accept this answer. You might want to ask a new question with the expanded scope.

Comment: yes bro I accepted. can I please ask you a question about javafx because I have to be with 5 days whether you know javafx

Comment: sorry because I'm new  in this site  I didn't  know this